# find value in array typescript & angularjs & ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have array and here is screenshot of this:
[image]

I have ionic app where i am getting some data from joomla, this is friends data but I want send friend request and if already is friend then not send.

so if in array is id like: 54306 then do something.

how to search id here? in typescript?

Comment: I do not understand either what you're trying to do what or what problem do you have. Can you clarify ? What do you mean by "How to search" ? If you want id 54306, then use `array[54306]` gives you the `friend`. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: Hi, I have array: this.user.friends (output is on screenshot) and I have function send friend request, but if already is friend (in this array exits friend id) then not send request. so i want search this id in array before send request

Comment: Then if the id you want to check is the variable `id`, check `if (id in this.user.friends)`

Comment: like this? if (id in this.user.friends === 54306)

Comment: No, `id` is the variable containing the value. If you have a numerical value, you could use `if (54306 in this.user.friends)` to check what you said.

Comment: yes this is realy good solution for this. thanks

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this in html? I do this in ts file and works fine but I would like to compare also in html

Comment: HTML isn't a programming language. You can't do that.

Comment: here is no solution to compare width *ngIf ?

Comment: you can add your comment as answer, I will mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id is stored in a variable named `id`, then `if (id in this.user.friends)` will check if that `id` is present un the array.

If you want to use that condition in an angular directive such as `*ngIf`, then you can do `*ngIf="id in user.friends"` still admitting the variable containing the number is `id`.

Comment: only problem is we can't add eg *ngIf="10 in us.friends" gives error: Can't bind to 'ngIfIn' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-list'..................

Comment: You wrote `ngIfIn` ?

Comment: No, I mean the error you wrote is "Can't bind to 'ngIfIn'", but `*ngIfIn` doesn't exist. You should write `*ngIf`

Comment: when I am doing this: *ngIf="10 in us.friends" gives error Can't bind to 'ngIfIn'.. maybe error message is not right.  I am sure I am doing *ngIf="10 in us.friends"

Comment: Ok, try `*ngIf="'10' in user.friends"` Maybe ? `'10'` instead of `10`

Comment: same. seems "in" not allowed here